# functional programming: idiom for dividing a list into smaller lists of given size?

Tags: list, functional-programming, idioms

Suppose I have a list and want to divide it into sublists of `n` size, with the last sublist being possibly smaller than the others. Is this a common idiom in functional programming, and if so what is it called?

An example of use of this function would be processing the items of a list in batch fashion.

I was only able to find one library that implements this function - Google Guava [`Iterables#partition(Iterable, int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe only Guava has this.

- In PHP it's called [array_chunk](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
- In Scala it's called [grouped](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#grouped%28Int%29%3aIterator%5BList%5BA%5D%5D)
- In Ruby it's [each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514)

Comment: I guess it wasn't so hard to find after all. Seems like there isn't a common name for this function, though.